# Helm - Override list values with override file

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I want to override values between prod and dev deployments.

The default values look like:

```
apps:
  myapp:
    replicaCount: 2
    containers:
      - name: foo
        env:
          MODE: "dev"
```

I can override this in command line with:

```
--set apps.myapp.containers[0].env.mode="prod"
```

However I want to keep all the overrides in a file and run helm upgrade passing in an override file as well. Adding the override in the file like:

```
apps:
  myapp:
    containers[0]:
      env:
        MODE: "prod"
```

does NOT work.  How do I override values inside a list?

Answer (score 2):

It is weird to say the least.

This worked:

```
apps:
  myapp:
    containers[1]:
      env:
        MODE: "prod"
```

So the index for `containers` is `1` when overridden in a file, however `0` when done using command line:

```
--set apps.myapp.containers[0].env.mode="prod"
```

Comment: When using helm better try to achieve this while using a template in deployment.yaml  and define these overrides in values.yaml

Comment: Yes, these go in values.yaml. However we want override for values in values.yaml for different envs. We dont want to duplicate values.yaml for each env, so we have a base values.yaml + dev.yaml or prod.yaml with overrides that changes only relevant fields.